# Bash nonzero test case (-n), [ and [[ are doing different things

Tags: bash

Usually i only use [[ for all kinds of test cases, because it's the most advanced way and it's more safe to use (Regex, ...).
I know that [[ executes different code than [, but according to the manpage and various documentations, it should at least handle options like "-n" the same way, but it doesn't.

> -n STRING    the length of STRING is nonzero

```
VAR=

if [[ -n $VAR ]]
then
        echo "\$VAR is nonzero"
else
        echo "\$VAR is zero"
fi
```

**$VAR is zero**

```
VAR=

if [ -n $VAR ]
then
        echo "\$VAR is nonzero"
else
        echo "\$VAR is zero"
fi
```

**$VAR is nonzero**

How is this even possible?

bash 4.1.2(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to quotes.

When you use `[ -n $VAR ]` the command that is executed won't contain any argument where `$VAR` should be:

```
$ set -x
$ [ -n $VAR ]
+ '[' -n ']'
```

This means that you are essentially testing whether the string `-n` is non-empty, because the following two tests are equivalent:

```
[ string ]    # is a shorthand for
[ -n string ] # which is always true!
```

If you use quotes, then you get different behaviour:

```
$ [ -n "$VAR" ]
+ '[' -n '' ']'
```

Now you are testing whether the variable is non-empty, so you get the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). You have to quote variables that you use in `[`:

```
$ VAR=    
$ [ -n $VAR ]
$ echo $?
0
$ [ -n "$VAR" ]
$ echo $?
1
```